# How do I add ucwords() on IntlDateFormatter()?

Tags: php

[PHP 8.0] I want to temporary change language just for displaying month as a word.
And this works:

```
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('Fi_FI', NULL, NULL);
$fmt->setPattern('d MMM yyyy'); 
echo $fmt->format(new \DateTime($w_date));
```

This gives me

```
10 toukok. 2002
```

But I want it to say Toukok with uppercase on first letter.
So I found out that **ucwords()** should fix it but I got syntax when I tested

```
echo $fmt->ucwords(format(new \DateTime($w_date)));
```

Where and how should I place the ucwords() ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ucwords` should surround the whole command, since `format` is a function of `$fmt`, while [`ucwords`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) is a function by itself.

```
echo ucwords($fmt->format(new \DateTime($w_date)));
```